# Importing methods that use global variables

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I have a question.

I want to keep all variables in one file, and the methods in another.

This is what I am thinking:

`file1.py`:

```
import calculations

a = 3
b = 2
c = subtraction()
print c
```

`calculations.py`:

```
def subtraction():
    answer = a-b
    return answer
```

The methods in `calculations.py` have to be utilized in `file1.py`, and they need to use the "global" variables stated in `file1.py`.

Where does my logic fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how globals in Python work. Globals are limited to the module they are defined in.

You'll have to pass in your variables as *arguments* to `subtraction()` instead:

```
def subtraction(a, b):
    return a - b
```

and

```
c = subtraction(a, b)
```

Note that you imported the *module*, so you need to refer to the function as an attribute of that module:

```
c = calculations.subtraction(a, b)
```

Alternatively, import just the function into your module namespace:

```
from calculations import subtraction
```

Comment: Do I have to use

    c = subtraction(a,b)

---
def subtraction(a,b):
    answer = a-b
    return answer

?

Comment: @tore: Yes, that'd be much better.

Comment: Well then. I guess that is what I have to do :)

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason i get

NameError: subtraction is not defined  ?

Comment: @tore: Yes, you didn't import the function, just the module. Updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

When the function is defined, the compiler assigns its "global" scope to be that of the module it was defined in. This scope does not change even though a reference to the function exists within another module, since the function itself is unchanged.